# Is there a way to stash working tree changes and the latest commit in Git

Tags: git

I have a cherry-picked commit and local working tree changes on top of it. I want stash these both so that I can switch HEAD to parent commit temporarily and then return it back to previous state. Is it possible to do this without creating a branch?

Comment: What is the reason for switching back to that commit? Can you just stash your changes and checkout that commit directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to create a new branch (although it's cheap and I wouldn't hesitate to create one).

The quickest way I can think of is the following (assuming your branch is called `master`):

```
$ git stash
$ git checkout HEAD^
```

*Do stuff on parent commit...*

Then return:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git stash pop
```

Comment: @harish: yes, but you would have to `git checkout` that same commit ID again. It's generally unwise to do much work on a detached HEAD, as it is too easy to lose your place. Instead, re-attach your HEAD by creating a new branch name.